# Symfony how to extend collection form field

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, custom-post-type

I'm trying to extend collection form in order to render it with its own template...

```
class ContactFieldType extends AbstractType
{
  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
      'collection' => array('type' => new ContactType())
    ));
  }

  public function getParent()
  {
    return 'collection';
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'contactField';
  }
}
```

And I use this type in this way:

```
$builder->add('contacts',new ContactFieldType(), array(
  'label_attr' => array('class' => 'contacts')
));
```

I'm getting the following error:

> The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class
>   MyApp\MainBundle\Entity\Contact. You can avoid this error by
>   setting the "data_class" option to
>   "MyApp\MainBundle\Entity\Contact" or by adding a view transformer
>   that transforms an instance of class
>   MyApp\MainBundle\Entity\Contact to scalar, array or an instance
>   of \ArrayAccess.

if I use this:

```
$builder->add('contacts','collection', array(
  'type' => new ContactType(),
  'label_attr' => array('class' => 'contacts')
));
```

It works fine.

I don't want to implement this data_class as suggested...I would like to extend the collection widget

Answer (score 1):

Your form definition seems fine and does not need more tinkering. Your problem lies in the instanciation.

From what I see, I believe you instanciate your form more or less that way:

```
$model = new ParentClass();
$model->setContacts(new Contact());

$form = $this->createForm(new ParentFormType(), $model));
```

However, the *collection* form types do not use a *Contact()* instance to work but an array of such instances.

Having fed your instanciation with a Contact() instance instead of an array of such objects, your code fails. What you need to do is:

```
$model = new ParentClass();
$model->setContacts(array(new Contact()));

$form = $this->createForm(new ParentFormType(), $model));
```

Although this is what I believe you did, you have not submitted the instanciation code so it remains difficult to tell if I'm right. If your problem persists, I suggest you provide it.